# Why I am getting error in contain query (trying to search /contain element)?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Could you please tell me Why I am getting error in contain query ?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/67b79/8

```
select * from Test where body @> '{"n","qwe"}::jsbonb';
```

**Error**

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Expected ":", but found ",". Position: 34 Where: JSON data, line 1: {"n",...**

Comment: key value pair ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your query:

1. `'{"n","qwe"}` isn't a value JSON to begin with. For a key/value pair you need to use `'{"n":"qwe"}'` (note the `:` instead of `,`)
2. the type cast `::json` must **not** be included in the string constant.

```
select * 
from Test 
where body @> '{"n": "qwe"}'::jsbonb;
```